# Error with the google foobar challenges

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-chrome

Has anyone had trouble verifying/submitting code to the google foobar challenges? I have been stuck unable to progress in the challenges, not because they are difficult but because I literally cannot send anything.

After I type "verify solution.py" it responds "Verifying solution..." then after a delay: "There was a problem evaluating your code."

I had the same problem with challenge 1. I waited an hour then tried verifying again and it worked. Challenge 2 I had no problems. But now with challenge 3 I am back to the same cryptic error.

To ensure it wasn't my code, I ran the challenge with no code other than "return 3" which should be the correct response to test 1. So I would have expected to see a "pass" for test 1 and then "fail" for all the rest of the tests. However it still said "There was a problem evaluating your code."

I tried deleting cookies and running in a different browser. Neither changed anything. I waited overnight, still nothing. I am slowly running out of time to complete the challenge. Is there anything I can do?

Edit: I've gotten negative votes already. Where else would I put a question about the google foobar python challenges? Also, I'd prefer not to include the actual challenge or my code since it's supposedly secret, but if necessary I will do so.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a specific programming problem; contacting Google would be better in this situation.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is a customer support request. See: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: Since StackOverflow is the first thing that Google shows for foobar fubar, I actually find it very useful. This is driving me nuts. As well as "Request took longer than expected. Please try again". Apparently there are more people attempting this challenge than it was designed to handle.

Comment: also, foo.bar cannot operate with 3rd party cookies disabled. It uses window.localStorage which is disabled when 3rd party cookies are disabled in chromium, see https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-localstorage-property-from-window-access-is-denied-for-this-document

Comment: I request a new one so the verify and submit works but the timer does not change.So careful to solve the new one with the remaining previous time

Answer (score 2):

Re-indenting the file seemed to help, but that might have just been coincidental.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, so I've done a bit of digging. I found [a google forums question about this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/glB446CoqrQ). It seems to be on their end. We'll just have to wait it out and hope that this is a temporary issue.

edit:
It is now working. It appears they were updating the system.

Comment: That google forums question is also me attempting to figure out what's wrong haha

Comment: That's amusing o_O. Well, given the number of people responding in kind and the lack of any stating that it works for them, my response stands.

Comment: I hope someone sees this. I don't have enough rep to comment. Unfortunately, there is no way of contacting google about this. Google requires that you specify which application you need support for and foobar is not listed. It is therefore impossible to talk to the help center and the only way anyone here can get any help is for someone to comment when it starts working again.

Comment: Heads up, it's working again. It appears they updated